# Prevent Double Animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

How  can I stop this function from happening twice when a user clicks too fast?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jTscroller a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#photo").fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
            $("#photo").attr("src",target);
            $("#photo").load(function() {
                $("#photo").fadeTo("fast", 1);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The issue I'm having is that if a user clicks too fast the element won't fade back in, it just stays hidden.

The issue wasn't what I thought it was. When I was clicking on the same thumbnail it would try to load in the same image and stick loading forever. The `.stop()` answer does fix double animation so I'm accepting that answer, but my solution was to check if the last clicked item was the currently displayed item. New script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jTscroller a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var last = $("#photo").attr("src");                 
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        if (last != target) {
            $("#photo").stop().fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
                $("#photo").attr("src",target);
                $("#photo").load(function() {
                    $("#photo").fadeTo("fast", 1);
                });
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you use the correct word in your descripton. Use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$("#photo").stop().fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `setTimeout` function to make a delay between click grabs. I mean, a second click will be processed only after sometime, after the first click. It sets an interval between clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `.stop()`
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$("#photo").stop(false, false).fadeTo()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loaded = true;
    $(".jTscroller a").click(function(event) {
        if(!loaded) return;
        loaded = false;
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#photo").fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
            $("#photo").attr("src",target);
            $("#photo").load(function() {
                $("#photo").fadeTo("fast", 1);
                loaded = true;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Keep track of its state

Answer (score 0):

I would prevent it like this:

```
var photo = $("#photo");
if (0 == photo.queue("fx").length) {
     foto.fadeTo();
}
```

I differs from `stop` as it will only fire when all animations on this element are done. Also storing the element in a variable will save you some time, because the selector  has to grab the element only once.

Answer (score 0):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jTscroller a").on('click', changeImage);

    function changeImage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.target).off('click');
        $("#photo").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            this.src = e.target.href;
            this.onload = function() {
                $(this).fadeIn("fast");
                $(e.target).on('click', changeImage);
            });
        });
    }
});
```